# Pipe Email to PHP Script

Tags: php, email, centos6

I have a simple php script that I want called when an email is sent to a specific email address and dump it into a text file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r"); 
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
$fdw = fopen("email.txt", "w+");
fwrite($fdw, $email);
fclose($fdw);
?>
```

- both result.php and email.txt are located above public_html
- email address was set up
- forwarder was created to point to the correct path for result.php
- permission for both files are set to 744

When I send an email to the email address for the pipe script...I get the email,  but nothing happens with the script.  I do not get any error message either.

I am not sure that the server is correctly set up so any advice on what to look for/change would be greatly appreciate. Running CentOS 6.6 with Php 5.4

Comment: what do you mean by ".I get the email" how do you know the script is receiving the email ?

Comment: use `<?php` instead of just `<?`

Comment: @Dagon sorry for the typo...fixed. I do not know if the script is even getting the email. I can get the email by logging into webmail.

Comment: if its being piped it shouldent be in webmail unless your pipeing a copy

Comment: ya...I am not piping a copy

Comment: then the pipeing itself is not working

Comment: any suggestion on what to look for on the server config?

Comment: how is the pipeing set up?

Comment: I went to my host provider and they said that everything was "setup" correctly...that it was a script issue. If it works on one server and not another...I am thinking that the new server is not setup correctly.

Comment: script should be rwxr-xr-x

Comment: I went through and found some errors on my server email log

Comment: 16 - |/home/database/result.php (user@example.com) <user@example.com> R=virtual_aliases_nostar T=jailed_virtual_address_pipe: Child process of jailed_virtual_address_pipe transport returned 1 from command: /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailexec


4 - |/home/database/result.php (user@example.com) <user@example.com> R=virtual_aliases_nostar T=jailed_virtual_address_pipe: return message generated

Comment: did you sort this? where you waiting for more feedback?

Comment: @Dagon I am still trying to figure out what is causing these errors. I had seen a post suggesting that Shell Access on the server needed to be "Normal", which it already is so back to investigating.